# What's wrong with this Node.js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, http-post

Some dude is trying to help me with a Node.js script.

See it bellow:

```
module.exports = function(context, cb) {

      var https = require('https');

      var body = JSON.stringify(context.data);

    var options = {
      hostname: 'seguroviagem.srv.br',
      port: 443,
      path: '/seguro-viagem/selecionar.json',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Token",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body)
      }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      var dadosRetorno = '';

      res.on('data', function(d) {
        dadosRetorno += d.toString('utf8');
      });

      res.on('end', function(){
        cb(null, { message : dadosRetorno });
      });

    });

  req.end();

  req.on('error', (e) => {
      cb(null, { message : e });
  });

};
```

And the API is giving this answer:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Compilation failed: Unexpected string",
  "error": "Unexpected string",
  "stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected string\n    
           at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)\n    
           at WebtaskModule.compileWebtask (/data/sandbox/lib/module.js:95:32)\n    
           at defaultJavascriptCompiler (/data/sandbox/lib/compiler.js:127:30)\n    
           at defaultCompiler (/data/sandbox/lib/compiler.js:136:16)\n    
           at /data/sandbox/lib/compiler.js:233:17\n    
           at /data/sandbox/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13\n    
           at Immediate.iterate [as _onImmediate] (/data/sandbox/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)\n    
           at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)"
}
```

What's missing?

Comment: Well, you never actually *send* the `body` anywhere, do you? Add `req.write(body);` before `req.end();`.

Comment: You are also apparently trying to send JSON data while claiming that it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That's wrong. The proper type for JSON data is `application/json`.

Comment: Nonetheless, this looks like the API server is failing to handle the request. This might be due to an error in the request, but it could also just be a bug in the server.

Comment: Yeah, without any info on what the body of the request being sent is, and what the server is expecting, it's searching for a needle in a field of haystacks.